# How do I install xcodebuild without root priviledge?

Tags: linux

I used to do `yum install xcodebuild` ,but now getting this error:

```
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

How can I install it without the root privilege?

Comment: You can't... with yum.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't install packages using yum without being root.  You'll be writing to root owned directories and updating root owned configuration files.

Assuming you have the correct sudo configuration, you would normally use, or might have used in the past,

```
sudo yum install xcodebuild
```

That will switch you to the root user and then perform the install, you don't need to know the root password, but you do need to have the right sudo config.

You can install local versions of some applications without being root, but you wouldn't normally use a package system like yum to do that.

Comment: Not working,I need to install it manually in my case.

Comment: 'not working' doesn't really help

Comment: `sudo` doesn't work if I don't have root in my working platform.Our team's setting is that you need to know root password to run `sudo`,so `the right sudo config` is impossible for me,I need to install it manually...

Comment: Or you could do the right thing and request that the sysadmin should install the package for you.  If there's a business case for it it should be done, and if there's no business case for it you shouldn't be installing it either.

Comment: @womble ,guys,let's be technical...

Comment: There is no technical solution because your problem is not a technical problem, it's a process issue.  You need root to install the package, either be root, or ask someone who is root to do it.  Otherwise, download the source and install it in your home directory, build and compile it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi can any one please help  me , How to install xcodebuild in linux